# Problema al pasar informacion de un JTable a un JComboBox

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo un `JTable` llena de información de la base de datos `sqlServer`, cuando selecciono una fila quiero que una el dato de una columna se pase a un `JComboBox` `cboCentroCosto`, pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Adicional.Objeto
    at Vista.frmControlDocumentos.tbSerieDocumentalMouseClicked(frmControlDocumentos.java:754)
    at Vista.frmControlDocumentos$6.mouseClicked(frmControlDocumentos.java:329)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
```

Este es el codigo que lleno el cboCentroCosto:

```
void CargarCentroCosto() throws Exception{
        Connection cn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            combo = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Objeto>();
            cn = new SqlConexion().getConectar();
            String sql = "Select c_ccosto, x_ccosto from fccosto";
            pstm = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();
            combo.addElement(new Objeto("0", "Seleccione"));
            while(rs.next()){
                combo.addElement(new Objeto(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
            }
            cboCentroCosto.removeAllItems();
            cboCentroCosto.setModel(combo);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                if (rs != null)
                    rs.close();
                if (pstm != null)
                    pstm.close();
                if (cn != null)
                    cn.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Este es el evento al hacer click a una fila:

```
public void tbSerieDocumentalMouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int fila = tbSerieDocumental.getSelectedRow();

        Objeto object = (Objeto) tbSerieDocumental.getValueAt(fila, 1);
        cboCentroCosto.setSelectedItem(object.getNombre());
    }
```

Esta es mi clase Objeto:

```
package Adicional;

public class Objeto {
    private String codigo;
    private String nombre;

    public Objeto(String codigo, String nombre){
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCodigo(){
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El método `getValueAt` devuelve un `Objeto` de tipo `String` *en este caso*, pero al hacer el cast `(Objeto)` muestra dicho error , para solucionarlo podría crear un Objeto y asignarle el valor devuelvo por `getValueAt` a un atributo de la clase. Qué por cierto hace falta sus `Setters` a la Clase `Objeto` , para posteriormente acceder a dicho atributo al asignar un `setSelectedItem` del combo.

```
public void tbSerieDocumentalMouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int fila = tbSerieDocumental.getSelectedRow();
    Objeto object = new Objeto();/* Crea el Objeto*/
    object.setNombre(tbSerieDocumental.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());
    cboCentroCosto.setSelectedItem(object.getNombre());
}
```

No olvidar que debe crear el constructor sin parámetros para su clase. Y sus setters

```
      package Adicional;

      public class Objeto {
       private String codigo;
       private String nombre;

       public Objeto(String codigo, String nombre){
           this.codigo = codigo;
           this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public Objeto() {
          } 

        public void setNombre(String name) {
              this.nombre =name;
          } 
          public void setCodigo(String code) {
               this.codigo = code;
          }
```

Comment: al momento que creo que objeto me sale error

Comment: Qué error. Posiblemente te falte añadir un constructor sin parámetros a tu clase.

Comment: me falta añadir los paraemtros

Comment: En su clase debe tener un constructor sin parámetros, así  `public Objeto() {}` aparte del que tiene actualmente con parámetros. Además sus setters como indico en mi respuesta.

Comment: si le quito los parametros al constructor, me sale error en el `void CargarCentroCosto()`

Comment: No dije que le quite los parámetros al constructor le **indique que añada otro constructor sin parámetros .** lo indique en mi respuesta.

Comment: cual le doy click a la fila me sale el siguiente error: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index`

Comment: pero ese numero es en la columna que se encuentra el valor que le voy a dar al combobox

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57910/discussion-between-dev-joel-and-angelica).